# Can we make synchronous queries with Beanie?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, celery, fastapi, odm

I'm developing a webserver using FastAPI, Beanie and Celery. The asynchronous nature of the ODM is userful when writing routers, however there are places where it is not required. For example, in a celery task I don't need to make asynchronous database calls.

Is there a way to make synchronous queries with Beanie?

I'm forced to wrap my celery task code in an async function and run it with asyncio.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [bunnet](https://github.com/roman-right/bunnet)!

It is a completely synchronous ODM developed and maintained by the same author as beanie.

See this excerpt of the [beanie](https://beanie-odm.dev) documentation:

> Beanie - is an asynchronous Python object-document mapper (ODM) for MongoDB. Data models are based on Pydantic.
> [...]
> There is a synchronous version of Beanie ODM - Bunnet